# Select rows from data.frame which contains identical values

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a `data.frame` having 4 columns with different number of rows. I read the file with:

```
df <- as.data.frame(read.table("Drug_Gene.txt", sep="\t", fill=TRUE, header=TRUE))
```

I want to subtract rows from every column which contains identical values. Colnames of my df are:

```
> colnames(df)
[1] "SOX2"  "EGR1"  "FOS"   "RUNX2"
```

First I tried:

```
first_two <- df[df$SOX2==df$EGR1, ] # Return those rows which have identical values in theses columns
```

But I got following error:

```
Error in Ops.factor(df$SOX2, df$EGR1) : level sets of factors are different
```

I think the problem is because of different levels:

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   329 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ SOX2 : Factor w/ 23 levels "","4-acetylantroquinonol B",..: 2 3 10 4 5 6 14 7 8 9 ...
 $ EGR1 : Factor w/ 127 levels "","(+)-JQ1 compound",..: 5 4 8 6 6 6 6 10 7 11 ...
 $ FOS  : Factor w/ 223 levels "(+)-JQ1 compound",..: 5 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 ...
 $ RUNX2: Factor w/ 21 levels "","(+)-JQ1 compound",..: 3 3 5 6 7 4 11 11 8 9 ...
```

Can anybody suggets me how I can solve this problem..? Thanks.
For reproducing purpose I also provide a input sample:

```
SOX2     EGR1     FOS     RUNX2
abc      def      ghi     jkl
abc      jkl      abc     def
jkl      abc      def     abc
lmn               jkl     lmn
```

So from such input file I expect following output:

```
   SOX2     EGR1     FOS     RUNX2
    abc      abc      abc     abc
    jkl      jkl      jkl     jkl
```

As only these are the values which appear in every column.

```
> dput(droplevels(head(df)))
structure(list(SOX2 = c("4-acetylantroquinonol B", "arsenite", 
"Estradiol", "bisphenol A", "butyraldehyde", "C646 compound"), 
    EGR1 = c("1,10-phenanthroline", "1-nitropyrene", "2,2,4,4-tetrabromodiphenyl ether", 
    "2-(2-amino-3-methoxyphenyl)-4H-1-benzopyran-4-one", "22-hydroxycholesterol", 
    "2-amino-1-methyl-6-phenylimidazo(4,5-b)pyridine"), FOS = c("1-nitropyrene", 
    "2-(2-(4-(4-nitrobenzyloxy)phenyl)ethyl)isothiourea methanesulfonate", 
    "2-(2-amino-3-methoxyphenyl)-4H-1-benzopyran-4-one", "22-hydroxycholesterol", 
    "2,4-dinitrotoluene", "2-amino-1-methyl-6-phenylimidazo(4,5-b)pyridine"
    ), RUNX2 = c("2-(2-amino-3-methoxyphenyl)-4H-1-benzopyran-4-one", 
    "Acetylcysteine", "arsenic trioxide", "Ascorbic Acid", "7,8-Dihydro-7,8-dihydroxybenzo(a)pyrene 9,10-oxide", 
    "Estradiol")), .Names = c("SOX2", "EGR1", "FOS", "RUNX2"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in `read.table`.

Comment: I also did that: `df <- as.data.frame(read.table("Drug_Gene.txt", sep="\t", fill=TRUE, header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE ))` and when I tried same `first_two <- df[df$SOX2==df$EGR1, ]` I am not getting the desired output..!

Comment: Or if you need to keep the columns as `character`, convert the vectors to `character` just for comparison purpose and get the logical index. `df[as.character(df$SOX2)==as.character(df$EGR1), ]`  BTW, `read.table` gives a `data.frame` output.  I don't think you need `as.data.frame` on a `data.frame` object unless it is just for fun...

Comment: this `as.character` is also not working !!

Comment: @Newbie Using the new input data, what is the expected output (as this looks a bit different than your initial dataset).  I find none of the elements in 'EGR1' match the 'SOX2'. i.e. `df1$SOX2 %in% df1$EGR1
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE`

Comment: @akrun: I think here problem is in reading the file correctly. I think R is reading the NA as `space` in columns which has not the maximumn length. How can I fix this issue to replace space with NA..?

Comment: @Newbie You can use `fill=TRUE` in `read.table/read.csv` and also specify `na.strings=' '` if it doesn't work out well.